# How to embed a link in a Facebook post through the Graph API

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post in behalf of the user a message that contains a link to another Facebook page. Something that is easily achievable through Facebook interface by choosing an autocompleted name of the page:

[image: example of the embedded link]

I use Ruby with the koala gem. I tried to do something like this:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
graph.put_object(page_id, "feed", message: "Embedded @[23497828950:National Geographic] link")
```

but it doesn't convert the link. I could post a full URL but that doesn't look as nice.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing as on Facebook (a linked page title) through the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

This can only be accomplished using the [**Open Graph Actions**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#pages).

```
POST /me/cookbook:eat?
     recipe=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/&
     message=You should really try this recipe from @[115401158528672]&
     access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you are not aware of Open Graph API, you can start from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Just follow the steps mentioned in the tutorial, quite easy to integrate and make your stories more beautiful.

Comment: Noticed the custom actions docs, but thought it was an overkill for my use case. Also it won't generate exactly the same result as making a link manually. It's a shame this cannot be done through the Graph API.

Comment: They are limiting the things just to avoid spams etc., I hope you understand.

Comment: PS you can mark it as correct if you think so to close the discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate your time. I've given you an upvote for now as I want to wait a bit for some other answers.