# Create post on facebook with iOS sdk which tags a facebook page (ex. @Coca-Cola)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I can do this easily from the web, by just typing @cocacola and selecting the fan page that I want to comment on.  However, I can't do this with the native facebook post view on iOS.  Is there another way to do this on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the iOS Social.framework, it's impossible to do that using `SLComposeViewController`. But you can implement your own UI for sharing and use the `SLRequest` class to send OpenGraph Actions request. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22635048/1310204) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782784/1310204) answers and [this Facebook article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions#mentions).

With the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) you can eliminate necessity  of creation your own sharing UI by using the `presentMessageDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:clientState:handler:` method of the `FBDialogs` class. But user must have the Facebook Messenger app installed on his/her device in order to use this API.